# isetool EnumerateDevices only returns 1 device?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, command-line-tool

I have 2 Windows Phone 8.1 devices connected by usb cable to my computer. I can use isetool.exe successfully with each phone individually when it is the only one connected. I know I need to use deviceindex:n but EnumerateDevices only returns one device (index 0) when both are connected.

I cannot find any specific examples online nor in the documentation that specify that 2 devices physically connected to the computer will be returned, the same line "Lists the valid device targets and the device index for each device" from Microsoft documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh286408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_Syntax) but that could include one device and multiple emulators.

I do not have any emulators set up to confirm if EnumerateDevices only helps in the case of multiple emulators and has a max of 1 device.

Can anyone confirm one way or the other, or shed any insight why i only get one device returned?

Answer (score 1):

Only one physical device at a time is supported; the others would all be emulators.